# Rep League should not show a user has earned 0 gold badges etc

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

http://www.imgftw.net/img/509848995.png

Comment: +1 and "yay!" for freehand circles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh, of course.  Fixed.